# Imprimindo sequência de impares de um numero em uma lista

Tags: python, python-3.x

Como faço para que meu código **exiba a sequência de números impares em modo inverso de um um número digitado pelo usuário**:

Meu código:

```
number = int (input())

if(number >= 2):
    listseq = list(range(0, number, 1))
    inverselist = listseq[::-1]
    print(inverselist)
```

Comment: Alex, sugiro fortemente você ler a documentação e buscar entender o que a função `range` faz e quais são os seus parâmetros. A sua solução está praticamente pronta, só falta acertar os devidos valores.

Comment: Mano acho que o mais indicado era o `filter()` vou tentar refazer meu código

Comment: Não, só o `range` faz o que deseja, usar o `filter` será desnecessário. Mas tente utilizá-lo também.

Comment: como assim só utilizar o `range`?

Comment: Você utilizou o range no código que postou. Não obteve o resultado que queria. Estude a função, analise os valores que você passou como parâmetro junto com o resultado que obteve e veja o que fez errado. Você literalmente só precisa alterar 2 valores no seu código para funcionar. Entendendo exatamente o que fez saberá onde corrigir.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A assinatura de [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#func-range) é:

```
range(start, stop[, step])
```

Se você quer listar todos os números ímpares no intervalo [0, n], basta você analisar que o primeiro número ímpar é o 1 e sempre o próximo estará a duas posições de distância; em outras palavras, pegar os números a cada dois iniciando em 1:

```
impares = range(start=1, stop=n, step=2)
```

Portanto, para exibí-los de forma inversa, basta:

```
n = int(input('Valor de n: '))

impares = list(range(1, n, 2))

print(impares[::-1])
```

Assim:

```
>>> Valor de n: 10
[9, 7, 5, 3, 1]
```

**Inclusive**, o valor de `step` pode ser negativo e você gerar a sequência já na ordem inversa. Basta lembrar que o valor de `start` pertence ao intervalo gerado por `range`, então você precisará decidir se `n` deve aparecer no resultado ou não caso seja ímpar.

```
n = int(input('Valor de n: '))

# Se n é par, inicia em n-1, se ímpar inicia em n-2
n = n-1 if n % 2 == 0 else n-2

print( list(range(start=n, stop=0, step=-2)) )
```

Assim:

```
>>> Valor de n: 10
[9, 7, 5, 3, 1]
```

Comment: Obrigado @AndersonCarlosWoss apenas mudei na minha estrutura do `range` para `list(range(1, number, 2))` que resolveu o problema.

Comment: A solução as vezes é simples, mais ainda me enrolo bonito.

Comment: Em programação a solução sempre será simples. Se ficar complexa é sinal que está fazendo algo errado.

Answer (score 3):

```
impares = []
number = int (input())

for numero in range(0,number):
    if(numero % 2 != 0):
        impares.append(numero)

print(impares[::-1])
```

Não é necessário uso de list(), siga esse [link](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/list) para entender o uso

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que a forma mais eficiente seria utilizando *list comprehension* (que é uma forma concisa de criar e manipular listas, ou seja, ele aplica a expressão em cada item da lista) desta forma:

```
number = int (input())
if(number >= 2):
    l = [x for x in range(number) if x%2 != 0]
    print(l[::-1])
```

Desta forma temos um algoritmo *stateless* a nivel de complexidade algorítmica é mais eficiente.

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver esta questão você pode utilizar **List Comprehension**. Desta forma, podemos implementar um código com apenas **1 linha de código**.

Neste caso o código ficaria:

```
print([c for c in range(1, int(input('Digite um número: ')) + 1, 2)][::-1])
```

Quando executamos o referido código recebemos a seguinte mensagem: `Digite um número:` . Neste momento devemos digitar um número inteiro e pressionar `enter`.

Neste momento o **for** percorrerá o **range(1, int(input('Digite um número: ')) + 1, 2)**, montará uma lista contendo apenas os números ímpares e, em seguida, exibirá tais números em ordem inversa.

Answer (score -2):

```
print(*reversed([*range(1,int(input('Digite um numero'))+1,2)]))
```

A partir da entrada do valor, será montada uma lista com os números ímpares entre um e o número informado.

Logo após, será feita a inversão dessa lista e a impressão da mesma.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).